# How can I do refactoring of CDK code using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, aws-cloudformation, refactoring, aws-cdk

I have created a CDK stack and put all my code inside (S3 bucket, Lambda etc.); the code is also in production, so I am not able to delete anything or lose any data and logs.

I want to refactor that stack in a way to create some kind of class that is separated from that stack where I'll put all those resources, and then call it inside of my stack.

I tried to do this but every time CloudFormation tries to create new resources. Is there any better way to do this, without losing anything?

ERROR that I get is related to "resources already exist".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the fact that when a resource's logical ID changes, the resource is recreated. When you extract your resources into a separate construct, you'll change the logical IDs of all its resources.

There is a built-in partial solution to this explained in the [documentation for the `Stack.allocateLogicalId` method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Stack.html#protected-allocatewbrlogicalwbridcfnelement):

> If a component is named "Default" it will be omitted from the path. This allows refactoring higher level abstractions around constructs without affecting the IDs of already deployed resources.

So if you instantiate your construct in your stack with the ID `Default`, the logical IDs of all your resources will stay the same.

An obvious limitation of this is that you can only have a single construct with the name `Default` in the same scope.

Another solution would be to extract them into a plain TypeScript class that's not a Construct, and simply pass the stack's scope to all the resources instead of passing `this` in the class.

Comment: Thank you! I successfully refactored my code using `Default` as ID. 

Another question if you can help me with this - I have API Gateway created using RestApi CDK construct, and after I did what you suggested it constantly creates new API Gateway and after that deletes the old one.

It has the same URL and everything, but different physical ID. Is there any way to avoid this @gshpychka?